Lower bounds with two paremeters
NB I use the Landeau notations in the following. Also, let us fix some minimization problem and call it $M$.
Assume statement $P$ holds true: For any constant $\alpha \geq 1$, an $\alpha$-approximation solution to problem $M$ requires $\Omega(log n)$ time, does this directly imply statement $Q$?
$Q$: for every $\epsilon >0$, a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation solution to problem $M$ must require $\Omega(\frac{\log n}{\epsilon})$ time.
The way i see it, since $P$ holds true, then if $Q$ is false, this means that there exists some fixed $\epsilon>0$, where $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation solution to problem $M$ requires $o(\frac{\log n}{\epsilon})= o(\log n)$ time, which is a contradiction to statement $P$ as for a fixed $\epsilon$ a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation is now a constant approximation and such a solution must require $\Omega(\log n)$. Is there something flawed in my argument? Thank you in advance
